# How do I find a finite list of polynomials $f_1(x,y),\dots, f_k(x,y)$ that generate the ideal $J \subset \mathbb R[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, polynomials, ideals

**The Problem**

Consider the ring $R = \mathbb R[x,y]$ consisting of all polynomials in $x$ and $y$ with real coefficients, and let $J \subset R$ be the set of all polynomials $f(x,y) \in R$ such that $f(0,0) = f(0,1) = 0$.

Find a list of polynomials  $f_1(x,y),\dots, f_k(x,y)$ generating the ideal $J$.

**My Attempt**

From what I understand, the elements of $\mathbb R[x,y]$ can be written as $\sum\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}x^jy^i$. This would then make the ideal essentially any polynomial such that all of the $a_{i,0}$ coefficients of y add to equal 0.

What I am having trouble understanding is how to find the list of polynomials that generate this ideal. Since this ideal mostly focuses on the coefficients of y, would the list of ideals simply be $f(0,0), f(0,1)$? Is there something here that I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Do you know a generating set for the ideal of polynomials such that $f(0, 0) = 0$ (without the other condition)?

Comment: No, I am new to generating these types of ideals. Do you know of a good way to research this?

Comment: The standard answer is that $\{ f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y] \mid f(0,0) = 0 \}$ is equal to $\langle x, y \rangle$.  If you can see why that's the case, then you should be able to come up with a similar set of generators for $\{ f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y] \mid f(0,1) = 0 \}$.  And then, what's the relationship between $J$ and these other ideals?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $<x,y>$? Is that just the ideal generators for $\mathbb R[x,y]$?

Comment: Yes, $\langle x, y \rangle$ denotes the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Okay, so would the ideal generator for $f(0,1)$ be <x, y+1> since $f(0,1)$ is a shift to the right of $f(0,0)$?

Comment: Close, but note that if $f(x,y)=y+1$, then $f(0,1)=2$ so $y+1$ is not in the ideal.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. would it need to be <x,y-1> since that would make $f(x,y) = y - 1$, so $f(0, 1) = 0$?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were told in the comments $J=(x,y)\cap(x,y-1)$. Since $(x,y)$ and $(x,y-1)$ are comaximal we have $J=(x^2,x(y-1),xy,y(y-1))$. Notice that $J=(x,y(y-1))$.